# Julia: Construct an array from an index array and an array to choose from (or: What is the Julia equivalent of np.choose in numpy?)

Tags: julia

In Python (Numpy) there is a [np.choose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html)  function, that constructs an array from an index array and a list of arrays to choose from.

Simple example (and I am actually mostly interested in this simple version of the problem with a 1D choice-array):

```py
import numpy as np
idx_arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 3])
choices = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30])
new_arr = np.choose(idx_arr, choices)  # array([ 0, 10, 20, 10, 30])
```

For the example above the same result can be created in Julia using a for-loop using list comprehension

```
idx_arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4];
choices = [0, 10, 20, 30];
new_arr = [choices[idx_arr[i]] for i in 1:length(idx_arr)];
```

Is there a Julia equivalent for `np.choose` or any other way to achieve this that does not require looping over the index array?

Comment: There isn't any need for the `choose` function in numpy either. This is ordinary indexing, just write `choices[idx_arr]`, it works both in Julia and numpy, and most other array-oriented languages, like Matlab and R and so on (with only slightly adjusted syntax.)

Comment: Yeah, looking at the answer, I noticed that, too. Still, thanks for pointing it out for any future readers not seeing the obvious (like me) -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`choices[idx_arr]` will work (note that indices are 1-based not 0-based).

The example in the question:

```
julia> idx_arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4];

julia> choices = [0, 10, 20, 30];

julia> new_arr = [choices[idx_arr[i]] for i in 1:length(idx_arr)]
5-element Vector{Int64}:
  0
 10
 20
 10
 30

julia> choices[idx_arr]
5-element Vector{Int64}:
  0
 10
 20
 10
 30
```

Answer (score 1):

[`getindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.getindex) looks like to be the equivalent of `np.choose`

```
getindex(choices, idx_arr)
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
#  0
# 10
# 20
# 10
# 30
```

In the manual is the line: *The syntax `a[i,j,...]` is converted by the compiler to `getindex(a, i, j, ...)`*.
So it is equivalent to:

```
choices[idx_arr]
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
#  0
# 10
# 20
# 10
# 30
```

A simplification of the for loop might be:

```
[choices[i] for i in idx_arr]
#5-element Vector{Int64}:
#  0
# 10
# 20
# 10
# 30
```

---

Benchmark

```
using BenchmarkTools

idx_arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4];
choices = [0, 10, 20, 30];

@btime getindex($choices, $idx_arr);
#  45.238 ns (1 allocation: 96 bytes)

@btime $choices[$idx_arr];
#  45.237 ns (1 allocation: 96 bytes)

@btime [$choices[i] for i in $idx_arr];
#  38.551 ns (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
```

Using the for loop is in this case the fastest method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the `getindex` function and also for commenting on the for loop! Great addition to the answer of Dan Getz.

Comment: Also the for loop is in this case marginal faster than the other methods.